# How to recompile the PHP with --with-pgsql

Tags: linux, php, amazon-ec2, postgresql

I have installed the postgresql, php and apache to Amazon Linux AMI. Now I want to use the phpPgAdmin, it prompts "Your PHP installation does not support PostgreSQL. You need to recompile PHP using the --with-pgsql configure option."! How can I recompile it for Amazon Linux AMI? Please suggest. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure there's not a some php + postgresql package available for that platform, rather than compiling everything from scratch?

Answer (score 5):

If your OS is RPM based (**Fedora/CentOS**) and you installed **PHP** from **RPM**, execute the following command:

```
yum install php-pgsql
```

If your OS is Debian based (**Ubuntu/Debian**), execute the following command:

```
apt-get install php5-pgsql
```

Do not forget to restart your Apache service for the changes to take effect.